# Sense resistor placement in switching regulator

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, current-measurement, switching-regulator

***Preface:***

I am designing a drone. My choice for stepping down voltage is to use a DC/DC switching converter.  After using the parametric search of Digi-key, I selected TPS54495RSAT‎ as my SMPS.

TPS54495RSAT‎ is a dual SMPS capable of 4A@Output1 & 2A@Output2. My SMPS design will output 5V,4A@output1 & 3v3,2A@output2.

My design also requires monitoring the battery/power. My choice was to go to PAC1933T-I/JQ.

[TPS54495RSAT](https://www.mouser.de/c/?q=TPS54495RSAT)

[PAC1933T-I/JQ](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/microchip-technology/PAC1933T-I-JQ/9453133?s=N4IgTCBcDaIAoEEDCBGAnAZgwFQLQEkB6AKQEUQBdAXyA)

Problem Statement:

Monitoring voltage, current, and power requires utilization of a sense resistor.

- Where should the sense resistor be placed? Before the feedback of SMPS or after?
- Will placing the sense resistor before the feedback compensate for the voltage drop due to sense resistor?

Calculation for the sense resistor was done using the datasheet.  It is specified in section *4.7 Selecting RSENSE Values*.

Resistor values:

- 5V - 0.025 ohm considering IMax = 4A
- 3v3 - 0.05 ohm considering IMAX = 2A
- sense resistor direct from battery - 0.01, considering IMAX = 10A.

Which one should be followed? Figure 1 or Figure 2?

[image]

Comment: It's not only about voltage drop compensation. You are actually measuring two different currents. Figure 1 measures inductor current and figure 2 measures load current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd place the feedback after the output capacitors, then measure the current after the output capacitors so you don't include measurement of the ripple current going into the output capacitors.
But before the voltage feedback so that the regulation compensates for any voltage drop over the sense resistor for correct output voltage.

Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmyVhW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You should always route the voltage feedback from after the output capacitors, even though it is commonly drawn before them in schematics.

Comment: Wow, Thank you very much for this. I saw the schematic of evaluation board & you are absolutely correct about the feedback.

But doing this will it not effect the Feedback loop? adding extra resistance etc?

Comment: @varun_koganti A low value resistor like that should't really effect the feedback loop. Too much resistance could possibly cause instability, but that would require much more. I have a design where I've even added a series diode before the feedback, works great.